# How do I render a CellRenderer to a Cairo Drawable?

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

The documentation for gtk2hs [CellRenderer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.14.6/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-ModelView-CellRenderer.html) says:

> The primary use of a CellRenderer is for drawing a certain graphical
>   elements on a Drawable

Looking at the [corresponding page](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/CellRenderer.html) for GTK+ I see it has a function

> render(cr, widget, background_area, cell_area, flags)

which invokes the virtual render function. However I can't find anything like that in gtk2hs.

So how do I get a CellRenderer onto a Cairo Drawable in gtk2hs?

Comment: Looking at the API, and based on this commit by Duncan Coutts (https://sourceforge.net/p/gtk2hs/mailman/gtk2hs-commit/?viewmonth=200407), that function is not exported by gtk2hs.

Unless you find a workaround, I'd suggest emailing the gtk2hs mailing list, and/or implementing the function in haskell yourself (using Haskell's FFI to rely on the existing implementation in C; see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.14.6/docs/src/Graphics-UI-Gtk-ModelView-CellRenderer.html#cellRendererStopEditing and the bottom of that file).